# Ban full width romaji tags

Tags: feature-request, bug, tags

Ｂａｎ  ｆｕｌｌ  ｗｉｄｔｈ  ｒｏｍａｊｉ  ｔａｇｓ

[ｍｅａｎｉｎｇ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%ef%bd%8d%ef%bd%85%ef%bd%81%ef%bd%8e%ef%bd%89%ef%bd%8e%ef%bd%87)

https://japanese.stackexchange.com/posts/25040/revisions

Please do not allow tags that consist purely of full width romaji. It's kind of distracting.

Ｐｌｅａｓｅ  ｄｏ  ｎｏｔ  ａｌｌｏｗ  ｔａｇｓ  ｔｈａｔ  ｃｏｎｓｉｓｔ  ｐｕｒｅｌｙ  ｏｆ  ｆｕｌｌ  ｗｉｄｔｈ  ｒｏｍａｊｉ．  Ｉｔ＇ｓ  ｋｉｎｄ  ｏｆ  ｄｉｓｔｒａｃｔｉｎｇ．

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create a link to [meaning](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meaning), it has the same description text as [ｍｅａｎｉｎｇ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/%ef%bd%8d%ef%bd%85%ef%bd%81%ef%bd%8e%ef%bd%89%ef%bd%8e%ef%bd%87) or [meaｎｉｎｇ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mea%ef%bd%8e%ef%bd%89%ef%bd%8e%ef%bd%87) (with mixed halfwidth and fullwidth characters).

However, the versions which contain fullwidth characters have no tagged questions listed.  This therefore looks to be a normalisation bug in the Stack Exchange software, as the fullwidth characters appear to be normalised to halfwidth in some places, but not others.

One solution to this could be to always normalise tags with fullwidth characters to halfwidth.  Alternatively, fullwidth characters could be disallowed altogether as suggested in the question.